# With return get only the one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file and I want to make a function to read line by line,and if finds a certain pattern in a line, copys it in a string. So something like this:

```
def readfile(file):
    lines = ""
    for l in file.readlines():
        if pattern in l:
            lines = l
    return lines


print (readfile(file))
```

Why it gets only one line. Is it a problem with return?
Can someone help?

Comment: You're just setting `lines` to `l`, change it to `lines += l`

Comment: Why not a **list** of lines (`return [l for l in file.readlines() if pattern in l]`)?

Comment: but why with print it works ?

Comment: @user3573552: printing is not the same thing as returning. Printing is writing data to your terminal. It *stays* written to your terminal even when you then replace the value in `lines`.

Comment: `lines = l` means: forget about whatever was in `lines` variable and assign this variable a new value taken from `l`...

Comment: please, do not use `for line in file.readlines():`, use `for line in file:` instead. `file` is already an iterator over lines in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is only returning one line (the last line that matches) because all the others have been replaced in the variable lines by the line of code

```
lines = l
```

in order to return all lines that match, you can either place them into a list:

```
def readfile(file):
    lines = []
    for l in file.readlines():
        if pattern in l:
            lines.append(l)
    return lines
    #alternatively:
    #return [l for l in file.readlines() if pattern in l]

lines = readfile(file)
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

or, return each line as you match by making it a generator:

```
def readfile(file):
    for l in file.readlines():
        if pattern in l:
            yield l

for line in readfile(file):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of lines to be l. This means it is overwritten during each loop iteration. Try appending instead.

```
lines = lines + l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `list(f)`, like this:

```
with open(path) as f:
    myList = list(f)
```